# What Are the Log File Names?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I moved my database files. When I go attach the MDF file by itself, SQL Server will tell me that it can't find the log files. How do I go about asking the MDF what files it is expecting *before* attaching it?

**More background information:** I have a bunch of SAN backup volumes. I attached them to Windows through iSCSI, and now half the drive letters are messed up. Moreover, I multiple volumes should be mapped to the save drive letter, so I can't restore the correct drive letters.

I know that the files are all there, but I don't know how many and which LDF/NDFs I should be attaching with each MDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to find those files with a detached database .mdf.  As Aaron suggests, you can create the database with `ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG`.  Another option is if you have an "old" backup file of the database, you can use [`RESTORE FILELISTONLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173778.aspx) to interrogate the backup file for the state of the database files at the time of that backup.  This will give you a starting point to track down your files.

**Edit**
Because I like Powershell, here's a script that will read through all the full backup files in a directory and build an attachdbs.sql in your Documents folder:

```
param([parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $dir,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $server)


#load assemblies
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null
$smosrv = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $server


#get backup files
$files = gci $dir | where {$_.name -like "*.bak"}

$output=([Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")) + "\attachdbs.sql"

"/*****************************************" > $output
"Attach script based off of backup files" >> $output
"*****************************************/" >> $output
foreach($file in $files){
    $rs=new-object("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore")
    $rs.Devices.AddDevice($file.FullName, "File")
    $hd=$rs.ReadBackupHeader($smosrv)
    $dbname=$hd.Rows[0].DatabaseName

    $dbfiles=$rs.ReadFileList($smosrv)

    "CREATE DATABASE $dbname ON" >> $output
    $filewrite=@()
    foreach($dbfile in $dbfiles){
        $filewrite+="(FILENAME='"+$dbfile.PhysicalName+"')"
    }

    $filewrite -join ",`n" >> $output

    "FOR ATTACH; `n--------------------------" >> $output
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I don't want to rebuild the log since I have the log files, and I just need to know what their names are. I would prefer to not have to go through the backups if I don't have to, but I may have to try the FILELISTONLY option.

Comment: You only need one backup, I'd recommend your most recent full.  The command will list all files in the backup, which should be all your database files.  Including the log file.

Comment: Well, I have about 600 databases that are backed up individually. =/ So even at one each, that's going to take a while.

Comment: @JohnTseng Or, if you can assemble all the backup files into one location, you could use Powershell to read through your files and report on the file locations.

Comment: That I can do. I have all the backups in a few locations. I can loop through them no problem. So I would `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` on all of them, and then query backupset?

Comment: I am more keen on reading through these backups than restoring each one. How long does it take to restore FILELISTONLY?

Comment: @AaronBertrand That part is no problem. I am sure I can whip that up in 10 minutes. (I am the programmer assigned this enviable task.) The difficult part is getting those 600*2 file names.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I was only talking about the last part where I already have the file names, and generating the create commands, but I will definitely post an answer when I get this.

Comment: This is going pretty well. I could restore 100 databases in 2 seconds. Then I hit a snag with the backups, but overall, I think this is going to work. Thanks a bunch to both of you!

Answer (score 5):

If you have the information for all of the backups in the `backupset` table, you can build all of the `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` commands this way, then insert the results into a #temp table, then use a cursor to build the eventual `CREATE DATABASE ... FOR ATTACH` commands. I still think it would be faster to suck it up and just restore the backups already, but to each his own I suppose...

First, create a #temp table to hold the `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` output:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE #x
(
  ln SYSNAME, [path] NVARCHAR(512), Type CHAR(1), fgn NVARCHAR(128), 
  size BIGINT, msize BIGINT, FileId INT, lsn1 BIGINT, lsn2 BIGINT, 
  id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, lsn3 BIGINT, lsn4 BIGINT, bsize BIGINT, bs INT, 
  fg INT, lgid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, lsn5 BIGINT, bid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
  ro BIT, p BIT, TDEThumbprint VARBINARY(32)
);
```

Now, based on the backups stored in `msdb..backupset`, generate the commands themselves and run them:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT *,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY database_name 
     ORDER BY backup_start_date DESC)
  FROM msdb..backupset
)
SELECT @sql += '
  INSERT #x(ln) SELECT ''' + x.database_name + ''';
  INSERT #x EXEC sp_executesql N''RESTORE FILELISTONLY '
  + ' FROM DISK = ''''' + mf.physical_device_name + ''''''
  + ' WITH FILE = ' + RTRIM(x.position) + ';'';'
FROM x
INNER JOIN msdb..backupmediaset AS ms 
  ON x.media_set_id = ms.media_set_id
INNER JOIN msdb..backupmediafamily AS mf 
  ON ms.media_set_id = mf.media_set_id
WHERE x.rn = 1;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Now, some of those might fail, if the `.bak` files have been moved. Also note that the `position` value is important, in case you have backed up multiple times to the same file. You want to be sure you have the most recent version that reflects the current file structure of the database (but there is still no guarantee that the last backup reflects reality).

Now, add a column to serve as a row number. **Warning:** this relies on "natural" sort order of a heap. If this table is super large this may not work.

```
ALTER TABLE #x ADD rn INT;
GO

;WITH x AS (SELECT *, r = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM #x)
UPDATE x SET rn = r
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
GO
```

Once you have the paths in there, you will see that they reflect the *old* locations and drive letters of the database files. You may want to run a query that replaces the known old locations with the new ones. For example, if you know that databases previously located at `C:\MSSQL\Data\` are not located at `D:\MyInstance\SQLData\`, you can run:

```
UPDATE #x SET [path] = REPLACE([path], 'C:\MSSQLData\', 'D:\MyInstance\SQLData\')
  WHERE [path] LIKE 'C:\MSSQLData\%';
```

Wash, rinse, repeat until all of the `[path]` values accurately reflect the *new* location of the files.

Now, we're ready to roll up our sleeves. This could very well serve as a bad practices, do as I say but not as I do post. We need a cursor to build the `CREATE DATABASE ... FOR ATTACH` commands. The following cursor relies on the `rn` column we added and builds commands that accurately handle multiple data files, multiple log files, or both.

```
DECLARE @ln SYSNAME, @rn INT, @ubound INT, @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
 FOR SELECT ln, rn FROM #x WHERE [path] IS NULL;

OPEN c;

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @ln, @rn;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SELECT @ubound = MIN(rn) FROM #x WHERE [path] IS NULL AND rn > @rn;

  SET @ubound = COALESCE(@ubound, 2000000000);

  SELECT @cmd = N'CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@ln) + '
    ON '
    + STUFF((SELECT ',' + '(NAME = ''' + ln + ''',FILENAME=''' 
      + [path] + ''')' FROM #x WHERE rn > @rn AND rn < @ubound 
      AND [Type] = 'D' ORDER BY FileId 
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
    + ' 
    LOG ON 
    ' + STUFF((SELECT ',' + '(NAME = ''' + ln + ''',FILENAME=''' 
      + [path] + ''')' FROM #x WHERE rn > @rn AND rn < @ubound 
      AND [Type] = 'L' ORDER BY FileId 
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
    + '
      FOR ATTACH;';

  PRINT @cmd;

  FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @ln, @rn;
END

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;
```

This will print a bunch of individual `CREATE DATABASE ... FOR ATTACH` commands. However they will only be as reliable as (a) the data in `msdb..backupset`, (b) the presence of the actual backup files, (c) how accurate the backup files are in terms of current database file structures, and (d) your re-mapping of old paths -> new paths.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Mike and Aaron's ideas, I created a short script to get the filenames:

```
RemoteAccess.NetUse("10.20.1.100");
var files = (new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"\\10.20.1.100\SQLDataBackup"))
    .GetDirectories("B3DB*")
    .Where(d=>!d.Name.EndsWith("21"))
    .SelectMany(d => d.GetFiles("*.bak")).ToList();
var filenames = files.
    ToDictionary(f=> f.Name.Slice(null, -4), 
        bf=> Database.Central().
            WithQueryOrProcedure("RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK='{0}'".Fmt(bf.FullName)).
            WithResult<DataTable>().Execute().AsEnumerable().
            Select(r=> r.Field<string>("PhysicalName")).
            Select(df => (new System.IO.FileInfo(df)).Name));
```

Then I found out I can't do this in the DR environment since the backups are not available in DR. So I will need another way to get list of files.

Comment: Not a 10-minute job, is it? :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Nope. I was only talking about the final part where after I get all the files necessary, to generate "Create database for attach...".